# Spark scala reading text file with map and filter

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've a text file with following format (`id,f1,f2,f3,...,fn`):

```
12345,0,0,1,2,...,3
23456,0,0,1,2,...,0
33333,0,1,1,0,...,0
56789,1,0,0,0,...,4
a_123,0,0,0,6,...,3
```

And I want to read the file (ignore the line like `a_123,0,0,0,6,...,3`) to create a `RDD[(Long, Vector)`. Here's my solution:

```
  def readDataset(path: String, sparkSession: SparkSession): RDD[(ItemId, Vector)] = {
    val sc = sparkSession.sparkContext
    sc.textFile(path)
      .map({ line => val values=line.split(",")
        (
          values(0).toLong,
          //util.Try(values(0).toLong).getOrElse(0L),
          Vectors.dense(values.slice(1, values.length).map {x => x.toDouble }).toSparse
        )})
      .filter(x => x._1 > 0)
  }
```

However this code can not be compiled:

```
[ERROR]  found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SparseVector)]
[ERROR]  required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector)]
[ERROR]     (which expands to)  org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector)]
[ERROR] Note: (Long, org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SparseVector) <: (Long, org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector), but class RDD is invariant in type T.
[ERROR] You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
[ERROR]       .filter(x => x._1 > 0)
[ERROR]              ^
[ERROR] one error found
```

But if I remove the `. toSparse` or `.filter(x => x._1 > 0)` this code can be compiled successfully.

Does someone know why and what should I do to fix it?

Also is there any better way to read the file to RDD with ignoring the non-numeric id lines?

Answer (score 0):

The code compiles successfully if you remove `toSparse` because the type of your `PairRDD` is `(ItemId, Vector)`.

The `org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector` class/type represent the Dense Vector which you are generating using `Vector.dense` and when you call `toSparse` it gets converted to `org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SparseVector` which is not the type that your PairRDD expects.

As for filtering non-integer IDs I would say your method is a good way to do that.

Comment: So why it compiles successfully too if i remove the `.filter(x => x._1 > 0)`